# Wait for all promises to finish

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

When writing integration tests, I need to make sure that all promises are finished before moving to the next test. I cannot know what are those promises nor how many promises are there.

I tried:

```
const flushPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate);
await flushPromises();
```

It doesn't work.

My jest version is `24.9.0`, node version `12.18.0`, react version `16.13.1`, react testing library version `12.0.0`

Comment: Is there any user-visible outcome after the promises all resolve? Typically with RTL you'd do something like `await waitFor(() => expect(getBySomething(...)).toBeInTheDocument())` - https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sometimes there are no visible outcomes. For example when fetching empty data from the backend.

Comment: In such cases does it matter whether it's resolved or not, then? Do you show any kind of "loading" state? What are you waiting to do _after_ it's resolved?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am calling api to clean db after each test. So, the fetch will be called after db is cleaned causing errors if I don't wait for it to finish before cleaning db

Comment: Why is that something where you don't have a handle on the promises to just `await`? I assumed you were talking about things happening within the components which they didn't expose.

Comment: @jonrsharpe because I am using react. The fetch is happening inside component. Db cleaning is happening outside of react like this `beforeEach(() => cleanDB())`

Comment: Right, I see. I think one issue is that your testing is hitting a DB _at all_; at this level I'd use e.g. [MSW](https://mswjs.io/) to test up to the transport layer, which would be much faster and give you more control over different kinds of responses. Testing _across_ the network boundary I'd do at an E2E level with Cypress or something Selenium-based.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't want to mock anything. I used to mock api before but it cannot show integration errors, and you need to change mock every time you change your api

Comment: That's why you have those higher-level tests too. Use the right tools for the right job. I talk about the various options at the various levels in https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2021/Apr/10/js-tdd-api.html, for example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you wait for all async code to finish before moving to the next test in Cypress or Selenium? I will need to clean db there as well